# Delete a file after process is close. C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I have a Windows Forms application that uses a temporary file while the application is running and deletes it after the main form is closed. The thing is that if I close the program from the Task Manager by killing the process, the file doesn't get deleted.

Is there a way to delete the file automatically when the process is closed in any way instead of the form?

Comment: No. Because when you kill the process your program not enters the closing procedure of the program

Comment: `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`?

Comment: If your process is terminated by the os (which happens when you use task manager), you can't do nothing (because - well - you're terminated). It's like asking "how to delete that file if someone pulled the power plug?"

Comment: Put the file in the TEMP folder and let the os worry about it? [`Path.GetTempFileName();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

another solution (very easy to understant) is to use an helper wich traps if your process exist, i am using this solution in lot of my program to supervise (i am not the author of the idea, dont remember where i have found this idea, i have just adapted the code): you could delete the temp file in the exited event..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Main App Process.
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            //Saves current process info to pass on command line.
            main = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            mainProcessID = main.Id;

            //Initializes the helper process
            checker = new Process();
            checker.StartInfo.FileName = main.MainModule.FileName;
            checker.StartInfo.Arguments = mainProcessID.ToString();

            checker.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            checker.Exited += new EventHandler(checker_Exited);

            //Launch the helper process.
            checker.Start();

            Application.Run(new MainForm()); // your winform app
        }
        else //On the helper Process
        {
            main = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(args[0]));

            main.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            main.Exited += new EventHandler(main_Exited);

            while (!main.HasExited)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Wait 1 second. 
            }

            //Provide some time to process the main_Exited event. 
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    //Double checks the user not closing the checker process.
    static void checker_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //This only checks for the task manager process running. 
        //It does not make sure that the app has been closed by it. But close enough.
        //If you can think of a better way please let me know.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr").Length != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Task Manager killed helper process.");

            //If you like you could kill the main app here to. 
            //main.Kill();
        }
    }

    //Only gets to run on the checker process. The other one should be dead. 
    static void main_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This only checks for the task manager process running. 
        //It does not make sure that the app has been closed by it. But close enough.
        //If you can think of a better way please let me know.

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr").Length != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Task Manager killed my application.");
        }
    }
```

there must be a better way to check for the kill, maybe trapping a message on the Task Manager, or hooking to Task Manager. But, the solution becomes more complex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` as described in the documentation of the [FileOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) for this use case.

The documentation states for *DeleteOnClose*:

> Indicates that a file is automatically deleted when it is no longer in use.

Comment: can this also be used when opening a file ? In my case its excel files generated by devexpress gridview in the temp folder, and after the generation I open them. I would like to delete them when the user closes them

Comment: @GuidoG what do you mean "when the user closes them"? Does the user open the files after you have created them or are you the last one who has a handle on the files?

Comment: My application creates an excel file in the temp folder, and then opens it. Now when the users is done and closes it, it would be nice if it would be deleted then

Comment: @GuidoG so you mean it should be deleted after either the user has closed the file in excel or excel itself?

Comment: Markus, that does not matter, if it only gets deleted when the user closes excel would be enough

Comment: @GuidoG ok, unfortunatly this is not easy to achieve as you need to monitor a file which is out of the scope of _your own application_. You need to monitor when excel calls [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/9b84891d-62ca-4ddc-97b7-c4c79482abd9) which is used for closing an opened file. So you will need to build something like [_FileMon_](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/filemon). A starting point will be [The reinvention of Windows API-Hooking](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/%2FArticles%2F27637%2FEasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking)

Comment: @GuidoG ... but this would be something for another question and another answer (hopefully not from me ;-) )

Comment: Well that is what I was thinking about. In stead off calling excel i would call an own application that will start excel, and monitor the file so it can delete it when no longer in use

Comment: The lazy programmer in me was just hoping there was an easier way